# Android - set width percentage to an editText inside a relativeLayout programatically

Tags: android, width, percentage

I have an editText inside a relativeLayout and I want that the width of the editText goes to the 70% of the total width of the relativeLayout, how can I achieve this? **without using a LinearLayout**

Comment: PercentRelativeLayout is now available https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html edit: sorry didn't see you ask about doing it programmatically.

Comment: @ziondreamt is ithere a way of doing it programatically

Comment: You can get the screen size and resize text view using percentage of screen.

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund yeah, but I need to it before the view is drawn right? I dont want that

Comment: @GustavoSerna Yes right :) , can you please provide little bit more explanation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PercentRelativeLayout` is recommended for your purpose.

But if you still want to use `RelativeLayout` and change the percentage in code, you can compute the width and set it to your `EditText` like this:

```
editText.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        editText.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = editText.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = (int) (relativeLayout.getWidth() * 0.7 + 0.5);
        editText.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
});
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: it is working, but now how can I do to add the "addRule"? for example: params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RightOf, tv)